# Cannot set user passwords

Tags: users, profiles, password

In the admin panel, if I go to "Users -> Your Profile" I don't have the inputs to set the password. I can only generate it, but I want to set it by hand. Is that some kind of bug, or was this intentionally removed from wordpress.

[image]

If I check html with firebug I can see that inputs are actually there, but they are hidden.

EDIT:

In some old wordpress installation that has not been updated I can still see inputs for password change. See this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fairly recent past, WordPress changed how the password change works. It *looks* as though you can't set your own password; but in fact you still can: Click on "Generate Password," and then, when the automatically generated gobbledygook password comes up, simply edit that field to type in your desired password.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security "feature" for WordPress.

If you can set a users password, you can then login as that user and have access to their profile, content etc.

There is a php function `wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );` you can use to force someone's password if you want to write some code.

There are plugins to change passwords such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-password-reset/

Finally, if you have access to phpmyadmin, then go to the wp-users table (assuming your database has the wp- prefix) and for the user whose password you want to change you click edit (as in edit that users's record). Type in the new password in the `user_pass` field, and in the functions column select `MD5` which will encode the password and therefore WordPress will accept your change and re-encrypt the password without altering the actual password you set.

You must then update the user with the new password separately, or via plugin...

Note that Wordpress has a filter called `show_password_fields`, so if you want yourself and all users on that site to be able to edit their own password (a reasonable request) then add the following code to your theme functions.php

```
function users_rule_show_password_fields() {
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'show_password_fields', 'users_rule_show_password_fields' );
```

If you want only the admin to be able to do the changes use this code instead:

```
function users_rule_show_password_fields() {
    if (current_user_can('edit_users') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter( 'show_password_fields', 'users_rule_show_password_fields' );
```

Comment: what about just for myself? why I can't set password for my account? I remmember I could normally do this in the past.

Comment: No problem - please see edit update

Comment: how would this code in my theme change anything here? we are talking about wp admin panel

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: i did.. no success

Answer (score 0):

The "Generate password" is what you are looking for. Changing of password and password/login in general had some UI facelift in 4.3

Comment: are you saying that this has changed in 4.3 ?

Comment: i don't understand why would they do that

Comment: almost sure it was 4.3. You can probably search for the relevant trac issues. Have to admit that I don't like it much myself (too many click required), but what was there before, was also confusing and bad in its own way.